# Linkedin Api to delete creative unable to call (getting 500)

Tags: rest, linkedin-api, api-design

Trying to make a call to linkedin api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives-new?view=li-lms-2022-10&tabs=http#delete-a-creative

to delete a creative however am receiving a 500 error

```
{
    "code": "GATEWAY_INTERNAL_ERROR",
    "message": "Gateway Internal Error"
}
```

body of the request is:

```
    "patch": {
        "$set": {
            "status": "PENDING_DELETION"
        }
    }
}
```

as per the documentation passed the header

```
X-RestLi-Method
```

as

```
DELETE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was field name

```
"intendedStatus": "PENDING_DELETION"
```